ERROR:indicators:Error in generate_exit: 'Trend_Signal' in Trading Bot Indicators
I have a problem while running my trading bot that involves multiple technical indicators to generate buy/sell signals. The error message was:

ERROR:indicators:Error in generate_exit: 'Trend_Signal'

This error occurred in the generate_exit function of my indicators.py script, which is responsible for determining exit points (stop-loss and take-profit levels) based on the calculated indicators. Here’s a deep dive into the issue and how to fix it.
The generate_exit function relies on several indicators, including Trend_Signal, which is calculated in the identify_trend function. The error indicates that 'Trend_Signal' was either not calculated correctly or did not exist in the DataFrame when generate_exit attempted to use it.
This is my current code.
def identify_trend(df):
    try:
        logger.info("Trend Calculation Details:")
        adx_threshold = 10

        df['Trend_Signal'] = np.where(
            (df['MACD'] > df['MACD_signal']) &  
            (df['ADX'] > adx_threshold) &  
            (df['close'] > df['Chandelier_Long']) &  
            (df['close'] > df['ZLSMA']),  
            1,  # Uptrend
            np.where(
                (df['MACD'] < df['MACD_signal']) &  
                (df['ADX'] > adx_threshold) &  
                (df['close'] < df['Chandelier_Short']) &  
                (df['close'] < df['ZLSMA']),  
                -1,  # Downtrend
                0  # Sideways or unclear trend
            )
        )

        if 'Trend_Signal' not in df.columns or df['Trend_Signal'].isna().all():
            logger.error("Trend_Signal calculation failed, defaulting to Sideways trend.")
            df['Trend_Signal'] = 0

        logger.info(df[['close', 'MACD', 'MACD_signal', 'ADX', 'Chandelier_Long', 'Chandelier_Short', 'ZLSMA', 'Trend_Signal']].tail(10))

        last_signal = df['Trend_Signal'].iloc[-1]

        if last_signal == 1:
            logger.info("Trend identified as Uptrend")
            return "Uptrend"
        elif last_signal == -1:
            logger.info("Trend identified as Downtrend")
            return "Downtrend"
        else:
            logger.info("Trend identified as Sideways")
            return "Sideways"
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in identify_trend: {e}")
        return "Sideways"

def generate_exit(df):
    try:
        last_row = df.iloc[-1]
        atr = last_row['ATR']
        chandelier_long = last_row['Chandelier_Long']
        chandelier_short = last_row['Chandelier_Short']
        trend_signal = last_row['Trend_Signal']

        # Exit logic based on both Chandelier levels and Trend Signal
        if last_row['Signal'] == 1:  # In a long position
            if trend_signal == 1:  # Confirmed uptrend
                sl = chandelier_short  # Use Chandelier Short as stop-loss
                tp = last_row['close'] + atr * 3  # Use ATR to define take-profit
            else:  # Possible reversal
                sl = last_row['close'] - atr * 1.5  # More conservative stop-loss
                tp = last_row['close'] + atr * 1.5  # Conservative take-profit
        elif last_row['Signal'] == -1:  # In a short position
            if trend_signal == -1:  # Confirmed downtrend
                sl = chandelier_long  # Use Chandelier Long as stop-loss
                tp = last_row['close'] - atr * 3  # Use ATR to define take-profit
            else:  # Possible reversal
                sl = last_row['close'] + atr * 1.5  # More conservative stop-loss
                tp = last_row['close'] - atr * 1.5  # Conservative take-profit
        else:  # No clear signal, maintain a conservative stop-loss
            sl = last_row['close'] - atr * 1
            tp = last_row['close'] + atr * 1

        logger.debug(f"Exit signals generated: SL = {sl}, TP = {tp}")
        return {"sl": sl, "tp": tp}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in generate_exit: {e}")
        return {"sl": None, "tp": None}
    
    
# Full indicators calculation and signal generation
def full_analysis(df):
    try:
        df = calculate_indicators(df)
        df = generate_signals(df)
        trend = identify_trend(df)
        exit_signals = generate_exit(df)
        return df, trend, exit_signals
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in full_analysis: {e}")

I have tried fixing it for several hours now. I see no problem with it. Do you know why I have this error?
